# Python: Why does the '0' in my if statement need parentheses to render true?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am brand new to Python and coding in general. I attempted to look up my question before asking... It's either I didn't look hard enough (I hope not) or didn't know what to search.

So, I am attempting to learn Python from YouTube (please don't yell at me) and I've been emulating the teacher's code and didn't understand one part of the if statement.

```
def helloWorld(myString):
    print(myString)
    myName = input("What is your name? ")
    myVar = input("Enter a number: ")
    if(myName == "Matthew" and myVar == 0):
        print("Matthew is great")
    elif(myName == "Bob"):
        print("Bob is ok")
    else:
        print("hello world")
helloWorld("Hello function world")
helloWorld("Hello 123 world")
```

When i run it in the terminal...

`Hello function world
What is your name? Matthew
Enter a number: 0
hello world
Hello 123 world
What is your name? Matthew
Enter a number: 1
hello world`

My question is about the `if(myName == "Matthew" and myVar == 0):` statement. I made sure both parameters were met on the if statement. But, it's outputting `hello world`. Can someone explain to me why if I put parentheses around the `0` it'll render the if statement true and output `Matthew is great`? As soon as I take the parentheses off the `0`, it'll render the if statement ``` true``false ```. Hopefully, I was clear and concise about my question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers . `input()` returns a string, and you'll have to convert it to an integer

Comment: `and myVar == '0'`

Comment: Do you mean (parentheses) or "quotation marks"?

Comment: @TerryA. I gotchya... So, I have to put `int` in front of the `input()` to make it an intenger.

Comment: @Ryan, Whoops... My mistake, I feel silly...

Comment: add '0' because input returns string

Answer (score 0):

Like TerryA said, replace

```
myVar = input("Enter a number: ")
```

with

```
myVar = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Alternately, replace

```
if(myName == "Matthew" and myVar == 0):
```

with

```
if(myName == "Matthew" and myVar == '0'):
```

Comment: Thanks Pete. I understand now.